# Idiom for handling size_t underflow in loop condition

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, unsigned, size-t

In C and C++, `size_t` is an unsigned type that is used for expressing size. It expresses intent and somewhat simplifies range assertions (`len < upper_bound` vs `len >= 0 && len < upper_bound` for signed integers).

(In all the examples below `len` means the length of the array `a`).

The idiom for a for loop is: `for (i = 0; i < len; i++)`. The idiom for  a backward for loop is `for (i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)`. But having unsigned loop indices introduces subtle bugs, and every so often I mess up the edge cases.

First, the backwards for loop. This code underflows for len=0.

```
for (size_t i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) { // Bad: Underflows for len=0
    use(a[i]);
}
```

There's the `-->` "operator" trick, which looks strange if you're not used to it.

```
for (size_t i = len; i--> 0;) {
    use(a[i]);
}
```

You can use a signed type for the loop index variable, but that overflows if `len > INT_MAX`. Many people and organizations considers that risk so minimal that they just stick to `int`.

```
for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {  // BAD: overflows for len < INT_MAX
    use(a[i]);
}
```

So I've settled for this construct, since it's closest to the canonical for-loop form and has the simplest expressions.

```
for (size_t i = len; i > 0; i--) {
    size_t pos = i-1;
    use(a[pos]);
}
```

### My problem iterating from `0` to `len-1`

That is, looping over the range [0, len-1). This loop underflows when `len=0`.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {   // BAD: Underflows for len=0.
    use(a[i]);
}
```

As for the iterating backwards case, you can use signed integers but that may cause overflows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {    // BAD: Will overflow if len > INT_MAX
    use(a[i]);
}
```

I tend to add another expression to the loop condition, checking for `len > 0`, but that feels clumsy.

```
for (size_t i = 0; len > 0 && i < len-1; i++) {
    use(a[i]);
}
```

I can add an if statement before the loop, but that also feels clumsy.

Is there a less bulky way of writing a for loop with unsigned index variables looping from 0 to len-1?

Comment: Why dont you check len > 0 and other bound before the loop?

Comment: Concerning the `-->` operator, put a space in between and it doesn't look as strange anymore.

Comment: I do `for (size_t i = len-1; i != (size_t)-1; i--)`.

Comment: Note that `for (size_t i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)` is an endless loop.

Comment: You could also use `ptrdiff_t` for indexing.

Comment: I prefer `for (std::size_t i = len; i--;)` for `i-1, ..., 0`.  It's clear when you see it more than once and does not involve adding or subtracting `1` (which is ugly and error-prone).

Comment: `But having unsigned loop indices introduces subtle bugs, and every so often I mess up the edge cases.` In that case signed  iteration would cause undefined behavior as opposed to unsigned one, because result of underflow or overflow is undefined and compiler, if able to detect it, is allowed to arrange code in way that it never happened. E.g. negative values as signaling mechanism (e.g. about error, or lack of required element) are signs of poor design for that exact reason in C++, that's why there is `.end() `value of iterator in containers.

Comment: Your first example is wrong even when `len > 0`. The issue is that `i >= 0` is always true.

Comment: @interjay yeah, and compiler simply may turn that into forever loop or may not

Comment: What compiler are you using? The positive values of `size_t` are not generally limited to `INT_MAX`, the normal limit would be `UINT64_MAX`. (or the equivalent `ULONG_MAX` ON X86_64. `size_t simply count negative. It was designed as a counter-type and negative-counts are only important in parallel multiverses.

Comment: You need to read the comment as well, @interjay. The first example was a counterexample that demonstrates where unexpected underflow causes bugs.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The comment states that the first example is only wrong when `len == 0`. My point was that it's also wrong when `len != 0`.

Comment: I'm not sure where you expect underflow or overflow, @Swift-FridayPie. Point is, that the underflow case can easily be reached with unsigned values when decrementing zero. The underflow case for `signed int` would require decrementing `INT_MIN`, which isn't likely to occur. Overflow cases are rare in general, because the range of integers often exceeds the range of valid indices by far. They deserve a different treatment still, because they can cause nasty bugs as well.

Comment: You're right, @interjay. So that first one even has two bugs. >;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt underflow (or skipping loop) happens actually more often that one imagines from strict point of view when we realize that comparison may happen between signed and unsigned AND how compile would react on such. Let say we had container that got method returning  unsigned value and we compare it to signed. Usage of unsigned value may result in classic logical error OP made here `for (size_t i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)` would be turned by compiler into forever loop `for (size_t i = len-1;; i--)`

Comment: Loop that works  `for (size_t i = len; i-- > 0; )`  Loop breaks if `i ==0`, because that's value before decrement. Using this loop with signed i might be UB.

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases here.

Iterating forward from `0` to `len - 2` inclusive

```
for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < len; ++i) {
    size_t index = i;
    // use index here
}
```

Iterating backward from `len - 2` to `0` inclusive

```
for (size_t i = len; i > 1; --i) {
    size_t index = i - 2;
    // use index here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i+1 < len; i++) {
    use(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In all these cases, you have one common theme: You have an index that has a start value. It gets incremented or decremented until it reaches the end value, which terminates the loop.

One thing that helps here is to make these two values explicit. In the simplest case, forward-iterating the whole range, the end value is simply `len`:

```
for (size_t i=0, end=len; i!=end; ++i) {
    ///...
}
```

This follows the general advise given to people using iterators. In particular, pay attention to the comparison, which works here and which is actually required for some iterators.

Now, backward iterating:

```
for (size_t i=len-1, end=-1; i!=end; --i) {
    ///...
}
```

Lastly, iterating a subset excluding the last `n` elements of the range backwards:

```
if (len > n) {
    for (size_t i=len-n-1, end=-1; i!=end; --i) {
        ///...
    }
}
```

Actually, what you were fighting with was your attempt to put too much stuff into the loop logic. Just be explicit that this requires more than `n` elements in order to do anything at all. Yes, you could put `len > n` into the loop condition, but that wouldn't give you clear and simple code who's intention anyone understands.

Answer (score 0):

> I tend to add another expression to the loop condition, checking for
>   len > 0, but that feels clumsy.

Your code should follow the logic. It is not clumsy at all. And it is much more readable for humans.

As the loop makes no sense if the `len == 0` and I usually use the if statement. It makes the code easy to understand and maintain.

```
if(len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len-1; i++) { /*...*/ }       
}
```

or you can also add the check in the loop. BTW you only check if it is not zero.

```
 for (size_t i = 0; len && i < len-1; i++) { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible answers for this question.  Which is best is opinion based.  I'll offer some options.

For iterating over all elements of an array in reverse order, using an unsigned index, one option is

```
for (size_t index = 0; index < len; ++index)
{
     size_t i = len - 1 - index;
     use(a[i]);
}
```

or (more simply)

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
     use(a[len - 1 - i]);
}
```

In both cases, if `len` is zero, the loop body is not executed.  Although the loops increment rather than decrement,  both access elements in reverse order.   If you are frequently writing such loops, it is also not difficult to write a little inline function of the form

```
size_t index_in_reverse(size_t index, size_t len)
{
     return len - 1 - index;
}
```

and do

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
     use(index_in_reverse(i, len));
}
```

To iterate forward over all elements of the loop in forward order, except the last, I'd make that explicit rather than trying to do it in the loop condition.

```
if (len > 0)
{
     size_t  shortened_len = len - 1;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < shortened_len; ++i)
         use(a[i]);
}
```

The reason I introduce the variable `shortened_len` is to make the code self-documenting about the fact it is not iterating over the entire array.   I've seen too many cases where a condition of the form `i < len - 1` is "corrected" by a subsequent developer to remove the `- 1` because they believe it is a typo.

That may feel "clumsy" to the OP, but I suggest that

> ```
> for (size_t i = 0; len > 0 && i < len-1; i++) {
>    use(a[i]);
> }
> ```

is harder for a human to understand (putting multiple tests in a loop condition, forces a person maintaining the code to actually work out what both conditions do and, how they interact).    Given a choice between code that is "concise" or code that is "less concise but consumes less brainpower of an unacquainted human to understand" I will ALWAYS choose the latter.    Bear in mind that the user maintaining the code six months later may be yourself, and there are few thought processes more humbling than "What idiot wrote this??   Oh, it was me!".